# How to get the follower count of my follower?

Tags: api, twitter, limit

I want to know how many followers my followers have (so it's recursively).

The Problem is obviously the API limit.

1. I read out my follower ids with `http://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?screen_name=username`
2. I request `http://twitter.com/users/show.xml?user_id=the_id`, but if I got many followers, I quickly get blocked by API limitations.

Is there a way to bypass this? For example, would this work for Twitter users with more than 6000 (or even infinite?) followers, if I ask to authenticate with their twitter account? Or is there another API call which may perform more requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use statuses/followers for your self, and page thru the results.

http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/followers

http://twitapi.com/explore/statuses-followers/

This will give you information on 100 followers per api call. In that result amongst other things is each followers, follower and following count.

6000 will only take 60 calls.

As this needs to be processed while authenticated you will also get 300 api calls per user.

Good luck.

Comment: Alternatively you can use http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/users/lookup this too can return 100 users at a time if you know who you want data on.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to combine multiple API calls to Twitter into one, like Facebook allows you to.
So there probably is no way to do this efficiently, you just have to spread out the calls over multiple hours.

Comment: what do you mean with "multiple api calls"? Because this are two different Calls? It does work, but simply not that often as I need. Also, spreading the calls over a longer time won't work, because I will probably call this function more often than the API limit may regenerate. Also, a User with more than 6000 followers would need then.. ehm.. 6000 / 150 (as I know, the actual API call limit) = 40 hours... o.O